# Query Join On two table fail at error code 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I get the number of rows on a constrained record by using

```
$table1="tab1";
        $table2="tab2";
$query=sprintf("SELECT '%s'.* FROM '%s' JOIN '%s' ON ('%s'.id='%s'.id)",
               $table1,
               $table1,
               $table2,
               $table1,
               $table2);
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        return $query->num_rows();
```

and I come up with the following error, I am using latest XAMPP with mysql version 5.1

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.* FROM 'tab1' JOIN 'tab2' ON
>   ('tab1'.userid='tab2'.userid)' at line 1
>
> SELECT 'tab1'.* FROM 'tab1' JOIN 'tab2' ON
>   ('tab1'.userid='tab2'.userid)
>
> Filename: A:\CodeIgniter_2.1.0\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

**UPDATE**

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.id=`%s`.id) LIMTI `%d`, `%d`",
                   $table1,
                   $table1,
                   $table2,
                   $table1,
                   $table2,
                   $num1,
                   $num2);
```

the error is

> Error Number: 1327
>
> Undeclared variable: 5
>
> SELECT `tab1`.* FROM `tab1` JOIN `tab2` ON
>   (`tab1`.userid=`tab2`.userid) LIMIT `5`,`0`
>
> Filename: A:\CodeIgniter_2.1.0\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Comment: Use backticks (`) instead of apostrophes around your table names.  Apostrophe is used for string values in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$table1="tab1";
        $table2="tab2";
$query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.id=`%s`.id)",
               $table1,
               $table1,
               $table2,
               $table1,
               $table2);
        $query=$this->db->query($query);
        return $query->num_rows();
```

I think your second query  should be like this.

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.id=`%s`.id) LIMTI %d, %d",
                   $table1,
                   $table1,
                   $table2,
                   $table1,
                   $table2,
                   $num1,
                   $num2);
```

Comment: Thanks but I stuck at the second query now.

Comment: Please check the bottom of my answer. I added a fix to your second query too.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects table and column identifiers quoted with backquotes, not single quotes:

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT `%s`.* FROM `%s` JOIN `%s` ON (`%s`.id=`%s`.id)",
           $table1,
           $table1,
           $table2,
           $table1,
           $table2);
```